# Empty result set and Case When = 1

Tags: sql-server, case

I'm pretty sure this is a implicit conversion but I wasn't able to find information about it.

Suppose I have this SQL:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN (SELECT 1 WHERE (1=1)) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

My subquery is returning one row and hence compared to 1. This leads my CASE WHEN to produce the 1 output.

Even if I set the subquery to return no rows like the sample below, the CASE statement returns  the 0 result:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN (SELECT 1 WHERE (1=0)) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

- Does the SQL interpreter make a conversion between "empty set" to 0 or 1 ?
- I don't feel comfortable using this type of comparison. In my humble opinion, it's better to use EXISTS like this:

  ```
  SELECT
  CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 WHERE (1=1)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ```

Is there any advantage or disadvantage if I don't use EXISTS ?

Comment: it interprets it as `NULL`...and `NULL` is not equal to 1...

Comment: If the sub query returns more than one row the original will raise an error. EXISTS wont. So they aren't always the same. If the sub query is correlated and guaranteed to return 0 or 1 rows per outer row you might also consider outer join and checking for null in the CASE.

Answer (score 10):

> Does the SQL interpreter make a conversion between "empty set" to 0 or 1 ?

No, The query didn't return 0 because the empty result is considered equal to 0 but because the empty result set is considered `NULL` and null isn't equal to anything.

As you found out

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN (SELECT 1 WHERE (1=0)) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Returns 0

But

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN (SELECT 1 WHERE (1=0)) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Also returns 0.

So the empty result set is not 1 and not 0, it's NULL as evidenced by

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN (SELECT 1 WHERE (1=0)) is NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

which returns 1.

See this [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=9c53fd434a57677d1b13277f30803b76) with that code.

`NULL` is unknown so SQL Server doesn't know what it's equal to.

> In my humble opinion, it's better to use EXISTS

If you rely on the existence of a result set, I agree `EXISTS`is probably the way to go. That's what the construction is made for.
If you want to compare 2 values off course you'll need to use `CASE` but for your stated scenario I'd use EXISTS

Your comparison will break if your result set has more than one row or column.

For example

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN (SELECT 1,2 WHERE (1=1)) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

returns

> Msg 116 Level 16 State 1 Line 2   Only one expression can be specified
>   in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

and

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN (SELECT 1 WHERE (1=1) UNION SELECT 2 WHERE (1=1)) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

returns

> Msg 512 Level 16 State 1 Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1 value.
>   This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=
>   or when the subquery is used as an expression.